# How to increase speed of matplotlib scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, scatter

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import cm

#from matplotlib.patches import Circle

ri = 100
ra = 300
h=20

# input xy coordinates
xy = np.array([[ri,0],[ra,0],[ra,h],[ri,h],[ri,0]])
# radial component is x values of input
r = xy[:,0]
# angular component is one revolution of 30 steps
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
# create grid
R,Phi = np.meshgrid(r,phi)
# transform to cartesian coordinates
X = R*np.cos(Phi)
Y = R*np.sin(Phi)
# Z values are y values, repeated 30 times
Z = np.tile(xy[:,1],len(Y)).reshape(Y.shape)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

ax.set_zlim(0,200)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.5, color='grey', rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0, edgecolor='none')

arr = np.array([[100, 15],
               [114.28, 17],
               [128.57, 18],
               [142.85, 24],
               [157.13, 26],
               [171.13, 28],
               [185.69, 29],
               [199.97, 30],
               [214.25, 31],
               [228.53, 32],
               [242.81, 35],
               [257.09, 36],
               [271.37, 37],
               [288.65, 40]])

#interpolating between the single values of the arrays
new_x = np.concatenate([np.linspace(arr[i,0],arr[i+1,0], num=20)
                        for i in range(len(arr)-1)])

new_y = np.interp(new_x, arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
t=np.arange(260)

tmp_phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20)[:,None] # angle data
linesurf_x = new_x*np.cos(tmp_phi)
linesurf_y = new_x*np.sin(tmp_phi)
linesurf_z = np.broadcast_to(new_y, linesurf_x.shape)

linesurf_c = np.broadcast_to(t, linesurf_x.shape) # color according to t
colors = cm.jet(linesurf_c/linesurf_c.max()) # grab actual colors for the surface
ax.plot_surface(linesurf_x, linesurf_y, 1.5*linesurf_z, facecolors=colors,
                rstride=1, cstride=3, linewidth=1, edgecolor='none')


cax, _ = mpl.colorbar.make_axes(plt.gca(), shrink=0.8)
cax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap='jet', label='test',
                       norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=15, vmax=41))
plt.show()
```

The problem is the speed. It calculates quite a long time but this is not the biggest problem. After the graph has been plotted, it is very laggy when I try to rotate the graph... Is there a possibility to increase the speed without to much effort? I googled and I read that maybe matplotlib is not the most efficient tool for plotting scatter plots. If it is true, is it very difficult to change the library? This is only a part of my code and further I am using canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib is not designed for 3d plots and is aimed at high quality (printable) graphs and not at speed. I would use another library such as mayavi for 3d visualization. Here is your code with mayavi visualization

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

ri = 100
ra = 300
h=20

# input xy coordinates
xy = np.array([[ri,0],[ra,0],[ra,h],[ri,h],[ri,0]])
# radial component is x values of input
r = xy[:,0]
# angular component is one revolution of 30 steps
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
# create grid
R,Phi = np.meshgrid(r,phi)
# transform to cartesian coordinates
X = R*np.cos(Phi)
Y = R*np.sin(Phi)
# Z values are y values, repeated 30 times
Z = np.tile(xy[:,1],len(Y)).reshape(Y.shape)

mlab.mesh(X, Y, Z, color=(0.4,0.4,0.4))

arr = np.array([[100, 15],
               [114.28, 17],
               [128.57, 18],
               [142.85, 24],
               [157.13, 26],
               [171.13, 28],
               [185.69, 29],
               [199.97, 30],
               [214.25, 31],
               [228.53, 32],
               [242.81, 35],
               [257.09, 36],
               [271.37, 37],
               [288.65, 40]])

#interpolating between the single values of the arrays
new_x = np.concatenate([np.linspace(arr[i,0],arr[i+1,0], num=20)
                        for i in range(len(arr)-1)])

new_y = np.interp(new_x, arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
t=np.arange(260)

tmp_phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20)[:,None] # angle data
linesurf_x = new_x*np.cos(tmp_phi)
linesurf_y = new_x*np.sin(tmp_phi)
linesurf_z = np.broadcast_to(new_y, linesurf_x.shape)

linesurf_c = np.broadcast_to(t, linesurf_x.shape) # color according to t
mlab.mesh(linesurf_x, linesurf_y, 1.5*linesurf_z,scalars=linesurf_c)

mlab.show()
```

Comment: thank you, but I don't get it run. I have a problem with the installation with mayavi. I tried to install it via pip install mayavi but I get always this error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yzxn3cgx\mayavi\

Comment: Are you on Windows? Then try the packages from [gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mayavi). Also install VTK, as stated in the link.

Comment: @Jannick now it's working. It is very smooth and I like how it looks. But now there are some new issues. I need my colorbar (based on the second entry of my array (15 ...40) like I had it in my matplotlib solution. I inserted a legend but the range was strange (from 0 -20) and I actually don't know where the data for this is coming from. Further I embeded this plot into a GUI made with pyqt5 and with using canvas. Is there a way to do the same for this mayavi plot? The last issue is the coordinate system. Is it possible to insert one like in matplotlib? Maybe I should get back to matplotlib???